# How were Icelandic bishops elected before the union with Norway?

Tags: catholic-church, election, iceland

By reading some basic texts (in English translation) (like Hungrvaka) I came to know that the bishops were elected on Iceland, and then had to make a journey to mainland Europe to be consecrated (Audience with the pope, then consecration by some north European archbishop) It is also hinted that the 'chieftains' had much influence on the election.

So my question is, that **who were to vote for bishops?** (After [Iceland accepted Christianity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianization_of_Iceland) in 1000, but before [they went under Norwegian rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland%E2%80%93Norway_relations) in 1262).

Where the clergy to decide? Or the gođar who had a say in the Allthing? Or some more general circle of landowners? And after there were more than one Episcopal sees established, were only those to decide, who lived in the now vaccant bishopric?

**And where there a majority vote, or they simply talked over the question and came to an agreement?**

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Comment: By reading some basic texts (in English translation) (like Hungrvaka) I came to know that the bishops were elected on Iceland, and then had to make a journey to mainland Europe to be consecrated (Audience with the pope, then consecration by some north European archbishop) It is also hinted that the 'chieftains' had much influence on the election.

Comment: Please edit that into the question; that helps significantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least two processes were used, according to Byock's *Viking Age Iceland*.

Bishops were at sometimes elected at the Althing. This was the case for Iceland's first bishop, Isleif, in 1055; in 1056 he traveled to be consecrated by the archbishop of Hamburg-Bremen. Isleif's eldest son Gizur was also elected bishop at the Althing, and also traveled to be consecrated, this time at Magdeburg.

After the second bishopric was created at Hólar, its first bishop Jon Ogmundarson was instead chosen "by the clergy and laymen of the Northern Quarter". He was consecrated in 1106 by the archbishop of Lund.

Comment: Please expand this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity_in_Iceland#Icelandic_Commonwealth_(c._1000–1264)

Answer (score -3):

The Vatican decides who becomes bishops, they were elected by the Vatican or people sent by the Vatican

Comment: I'm not sure this is true in the referenced time period. Can you provide sources?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but the Vatican wasn't even the seat of the Papacy during this time -- It was [St John Lateran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archbasilica_of_St._John_Lateran).  Also, this was the [dark age of the Papacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saeculum_obscurum), when the Popes were puppets of local Roman noble families.  Finally, Iceland was Christianized by missionaries from Armenia.